# What did male motorcyclists wear in 1930s England?

Tags: england, clothing, fashion, 1930s

What did male motorcyclists wear in 1930s England? I'm assuming the outfits from [Watch This Club Ride Vintage 1930s Motorcycles Across France](https://www.rideapart.com/news/356572/1930s-motorcycles-across-france-video/) are probably pretty accurate, as well as the top image results for [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=1930s%20motorcyclist). But I wanted to see if anyone has any better sources of information on this topic. Also, I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could put names to the specific articles of clothing, in addition to pictures, as I'm attempting to create a costume.

Comment: The question was phrased as speculation, which generally will earn a question here close votes. However, there's no reason it needed to be, as we know such people existed, so I rephrased it for you.

Answer (score 2):

This is very interesting, yet very difficult to find much information. You will likely have to combine multiple sources to find your answer.

I like the 2 sources you already have, and [pandomoto.com](https://pandomoto.com/blog/history-of-motorcycle-apparel/) is another one.

From skull caps to leather padding, the military had a lot to do with the style of motorcyclist fashion. I hope this helps!